# Magento migration 1.9.3.1 to 2.3.5 p2

Tags: magento2, database, upgrade, migration, cli

[image]When i doing migration from magento 1.9.3.1 to magento 2.3.5 p2 getting this error. And after search this related issue i deleted some database tables but again and again i getting this issue on migrate:data command. But i do migrate this magento 1 version with magento 2.3.4 it will be done without any issue so anyone will be able to tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you able to migrate to magento 2.3.4 without any issue?

Comment: yes but getting error on magento 2.3.5 p1 and p2

Comment: Is site working properly with magento 2.3.4 after migration?

Comment: yes both frontend and backend working perfectly.

Comment: As per my suggestion please upgrade now to version 2.3.4-p2

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.But i want to migrate in magento 2.3.5 so can you guide me how can i do without any error?

Comment: I got a related duplicate key error on EAV_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_CODE, and resolved that by a similar approach: UPDATE eav_attribute_group SET attribute_group_name = CONCAT(attribute_group_name, "_", attribute_set_id) WHERE attribute_group_name = "General";

Comment: Is this working for you as well?

Comment: No it's not working.